# UITableView deselects cell when entering edit mode

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to enter edit mode when user selects a cell (if not in edit mode) and exit edit mode when user selects a selected cell (and is in edit mode, obviously).  I have everything working except for this slight problem: When the table view is not in edit mode and the user selects a cell, the cell highlights but then immediately "deselects", ie. the selected background flashes and then disappears.  I have confirmed that immediately after the call to `setEditing:animated:` the tableview's selected cell is nil.  I want it to maintain its selected cell after the call to `setEditing:animated:`  Unfortunately, even calling `selectRow:animated:scrollPosition:` after `setEditing:animated:` doesn't properly select the cell.

Comment: Adding to this problem is that the `UITableView` doesn't even call the delegate methods `-tableView:willDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` and `-tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:` when the automatic deselection happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check the table view's **editing** property. Select Single selection During editing

[image]

Comment: I thought this would solve it too but it doesn't. In my case, I have Multiple Selection enabled for the table view. When I give Multiple Selection During Editing, swiping doesn't even work! And when I give Single Selection During Editing as shown in the image, swiping works but the automatic deselection still happens.

Comment: This determines whether the user can make new selections not whether the current cell will be deselected during editing.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614889-allowsselectionduringediting